# How to json output whole scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debugging

`{foo|json}` works well to output a subset of $scope. How to send whole scope to the `json` filter?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the JSON filter will not allow you to output the entire `$scope` object, even if you try to trick it by using `controllerAs` syntax and attaching the injected `$scope` to your context.

Template:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl as vm">
        <div ng-bind="vm.foo | json"></div>
        <div ng-bind="vm.scope | json"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.foo = {
          bar: "test bar",
          foobar: "test foobar"
        };

        vm.scope = $scope;

        console.log(vm.scope);
    });
```

In this example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50n7ycmy/),

```
{ "bar": "test bar", "foobar": "test foobar" }
```

is outputted for `vm.foo` but

```
"$SCOPE"
```

is outputted for `vm.scope`.

As a result, it would appear you can't send the actual scope object to the json filter.  You would need to loop through and create a new object with only the pertinent data you need.  You can't use `angular.copy` in this instance, since angular will prohibit it.

Answer (score 0):

Angular Have it's own toJSON function, which prevent you from normally doing it.

```
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') return undefined;
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty ? '  ' : null);
}

function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
  ....
  } else if (isScope(value)) {
    val = '$SCOPE';
  }
  ....
}
```

Unless you do like this, may be kind of a hack, since this === $scope in angular templates.

```
<div ng-repeat="(k, v) in ($$=this)">
    <div ng-if="k!='$$' && k!='this'">key: {{k}}
        <pre ng-bind="$$[k]|json:4"></pre>
    </div>
</div>
```

Full Snippet or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SE_YOU/r6kLoq76/1/)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.foo = {
    bar: "test bar",
    foobar: "test foobar"
  };

  $scope.zzz = {
    bar: "test bar",
    foobar: "test foobar"
  };

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in ($$=this)">
            <div ng-if="k!='$$' && k!='this'">key: {{k}}
                <pre ng-bind="$$[k]|json:4"></pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

or If you want to get $scope as single object JSON, you can do like here or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SE_YOU/r6kLoq76/2/)

```
<div ng-init="$scope={}">
    <div ng-repeat="(k, v) in ($$=this)" ng-init="$scope[k] = $$[k]" ng-if="k!=='$$'&&k!=='this'&&k!=='$scope'">
    </div>
</div>
<pre ng-bind="$scope|json:4"></pre>
```

which output

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "test bar",
    "foobar": "test foobar"
  },
  "zzz": {
    "bar": "test bar",
    "foobar": "test foobar"
  }
}
```